# How can I make the bootstrap dropdown open on the last position before closed?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, dropdown, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown that when I choose an item, and close the dropdown, when I reopen the dropdown it opens back at the top of the list. I believe with normal divs it opens back in the scroll position of where it was last closed. Is there any way I can revert to this behavior with Angular Bootstrap?

Thanks.

The code:

```
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <div [autoClose]="'outside'" ngbDropdown #testdd="ngbDropdown">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngbDropdownToggle ></button>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="sourceDropdown" class="form-inline pl-0 mb-2 dropdownBody">
                      <div>
                          <div *ngFor="let val of testVals" class="form-check context-dropdown-item source-dropdown-item" (click)="chooseTest(testdd)" ngbDropdownItem>
                              <label class="form-check-label context-dropdown-text">
                                  <img class="prefix-icon icon-md float-left mr-2">
                                  {{val}}
                              </label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

may be your code is broken, try this

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head><body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
        
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
        
        
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```